# Script does work properly right after the first run

Tags: bash, socket, c++

I have a problem with running the same script right after its first run finished. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

./program1 &
./program2 &
./program3
wait
```

Briefly, the inner three C++ programs need to run at the same time and they communicate with each other via a pairwise socket connection. In the first run, everything works fine. However, when I rerun the script right after the first one, it does not work at all. It is not giving any error either. If I wait for a while and then run it again, it works fine again. I could not figure out the underlying reason for such a behaviour. I would be glad if you can help me understand it.

Comment: Isn't this down to the way your C++ programs communicate? Presumably, if you re-run the script immediately, the C++ programs are still running so their communication gets confused because of the new instances? There's nothing special in the shell script, I don't think we can help you on this one.

Comment: Debug that `wait`. Before it, `jobs`. After it, `echo "Wait status $?"`. Then `jobs` again. Also note, the wait does not apply to any child processes started by your three C++ programs: they must tidy their own children and any threads.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seems to indicate that the problem is in the C++ programs: they can't find the right process to communicate with when multiple instances are running. This explains why it only fails if you run the script again "right after the first one" and why it works fine if you wait a bit before trying again.

Presumably, the C++ programs are still running the first time you try to re-run, and that causes the problem, and they have finished if you wait a bit between launches, which is why they work as expected.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `wait` to not wait for programs 1 and 2? Would it be preferable to background program3 too, for symmetry?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I suppose that depends on what the tools are doing. If `program3` will always finish before the others, there's no benefit in sending it to the background. If not, then that's why the `wait` is there: so that the script doesn't exit when programs 1 and 2 finish.

Comment: I'm relying on the OP saying ".. same script right *after* its first run *finished*", which implies the script exited, so the wait happened, and all 3 programs ended either before or inside the wait. So either the script is being run twice simultaneously, or there are extraneous descendants, or the wait drops through, or there are delays in unclosed sockets being timed out (my money is on that one).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the OP doesn't say that though, they say "rerun the script right after the first one", so it isn't clear that it has indeed finished. In any case, as you correctly point out, if the C++ processes are spawning children, the `wait` won't wait for those, so you have precisely this problem.

Comment: I quoted the first sentence verbatim. The sentence starting "However.." is more ambiguous, but not actually contradictory. The only resolution to this is probably having the drains up on the C++ code, and some serious diagnostics injected after the wait to discover stray processes and hanging sockets.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant ha! You did indeed, I had managed to completely miss that first sentence, my bad.